# How to know Helper Tool is Installed or Not for MAC Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, networking, helper, system-configuration

I am working on MAC Application in which I have used Helper Tool to do some privilege stuff for my application.

Now How can I check whether **command line helper tool** already installed or not from my application.

**It may be the case where user manually delete the helper tool from \Library\PrivilageHelperTool**

Comment: Is the app sandboxed?

Comment: No app does not have sandbox

Comment: And why can't you bundle the helper tool within the app bundle?

Comment: I didn't get that can you explain your comment

Comment: Okey I got your thought.. To store the Helper Tool in app bundle is useless as it need to be stored under \Library\PrivilageHelperTool to do task as admin.

Comment: OK, so to answer your question use `[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]`.

Comment: It Worked Thanks... I really forgot to check like this...